# Twig token "punctuation"

Tags: php, syntax, twig, template-engine

I tried to cut printed string by limiting it to 50 symbols:

```
<p class="posttext">{{ post.Text [:50] }}</p>
```

but it threw me a Twig_Error_Syntax error:

```
Message: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" in "home.php" at line 15
```

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Just a hunch: try removing the space before the `[`.

Comment: @EDCottrell nope. It doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, second theory: `{{ post.Text[0:50] }}`

Comment: The `[ : ]` shortcut was introduced in Twig 1.6.0 version (released on 2012-02-04). Is it possible that you are using an even older Twig version? This should work without problems: `{{ post.Text[:50] }}`